# What is the most efficient way to process a multiple value method return?

Tags: android, performance

I have a method that returns `Point`:

```
private Point getDisplayWH() {

    Display display = this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {
        Point realWH = new Point();
        display.getSize(realWH);
        return realWH;
    }
    return new Point(display.getWidth(), display.getHeight());
}
```

Now, when receiving this result, I can't decide **which** of these two **is more efficient**.

**Number 1**:

```
Point displayWH = getDisplayWH();
layoutPreviewDim = calcCamPrevDimensions(displayWH.x, displayWH.y));
```

**Number 2**:

```
layoutPreviewDim = calcCamPrevDimensions(getDisplayWH().x, getDisplayWH().y));
```

In [this article](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html) it is said that:

> If you have a method returning a string, and you know that its result will always be appended to a StringBuffer anyway, change your signature and implementation so that the function does the append directly, instead of creating a short-lived temporary object.

But should I follow these instructions even if I have to call the method more than once to get the return? What about `display` variable in my `getDisplayWH()` method? Is it more efficient approach than accessing `Display` methods directly `this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().xxxx`?

And my second side question: Is there a general way to check/compare code efficiency other than with system time difference before and after method call? Or the time difference is the ultimate tool?

Comment: How often do you call this method? Few times per second? Few million times per second?

Comment: In this case, just once, in `onCreate`. I know it doesn't matter much in this example. But is there some unwritten rule, which says, this is the way you should always do it?

Comment: Yes, there is: optimize only when you measured that your code works inefficiently. Otherwise just write code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling a method twice rather than storing the return value is going to be inefficient.

One way to test for efficiency is to write a unit test and perhaps use the two approaches, call them 10k times in a loop, and see what happens.

But, regardless, try to minimize calling methods multiple times, if they return the same value on each call.

The point about the string is that strings have to be garbage collected, as they are not appended to.  So you create extra objects that will need to be collected. So, appending it directly to the `StringBuffer` just makes sense to limit how long the garbage collector runs.

If you go with the unit test approach, you can also monitor garbage collection to see what the difference is.

One way to monitor garbage collection is to follow this article:
http://www.raizlabs.com/dev/2014/04/hunting-your-leaks-memory-management-in-android-part-2-of-2/

Once way is to use `DDMS` and cause a garbage collection to see how much memory has been allocated, but there are other approaches.

Comment: I agree with @JamesBlack however, this may be premature optimization. Unless this gets called very frequently,  it probably doesnt matter.

Comment: @GreyBeardedGeek I agree it doesn't matter much on this one example. But I would like to learn the right programing habits, so when it does matter I choose the optimal way.